# Assets Forbidden on Rails Production Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, http-status-code-403

I am attempting to deploy a rails app onto an Apache server. I am attempting to access jquery in the app's assets folder with:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am also attempting to load a custom script with a javascript_include_tag. As I look in the javascript console of my web browser, I see that the server responds with a 403 forbidden error code when trying to access these scripts.

I attempted to chmod 775 my /var/www//public/assets folder but this did not resolve the problem. I have tried both running rake assets:precompile and changing the production.rb to serve static files and setting config.assets.compile to true.

Comment: It works because you have overridden the application to allow for "fallback to the assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed" This tells you that even though you precompiled assets something else in your application configuration is wrong. Doing it this way and just overriding it only masks the symptoms and more than likely it will cause more problems as you move forward. Not to mention the security implications.
I would suggest you look in your config/initializers/assets.rb and make sure everything is setup properly there as well if you are using rails 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works, but I ran

```
rm -rf public/assets
```

in my application directory and changed my production.rb so that

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your /config/environments/production.rb has eager load enabled.

Comment: Try removing the / from the beginning of the src attribute "assets/jquery.js" . I have seen depending on how a rails app is setup the / at the beginning breaks some things.